# Using Ubuntu and Win7 on two drives

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, system

I would like to dualboot. I have ubuntu 13.10 on one hard drive and Win7 Home on another. I’ve been using Ubuntu for a long time but I don’t know where to start. What is the easy way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually choose which hard drive to boot from on each boot through the bios: holding 'Delete', 'F1', 'F12', or 'F10' are common ways to get to bios, and from there you can choose a default boot device, as well as to override that default and boot from a specified drive at that time.